# Why does my page go blank?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

As soon as I hit `save` on my IDE & hit `refresh` on my browser to test my `prompt()` function in my `index.js` file, my entire page goes blank causing me not to see anything, just a white screen.  I could've sworn my function is syntactically correct.  Everything else works perfect except when that `prompt()` function is included.

Here's my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
     <title>name name</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="body.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.16/browser.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="firstBar"></div>
    <div id="body"></div>

    <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="body.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here's my `index.js` file:

```
 var TitleBar = React.createClass({
  prompt: function() {
    alert("This works!");
  }

  render: function() {
    return(
     <div className="jumbotron">
      <div className="container">
      <kbd className="fullName"name name/kbd>
        <button onClick={this.prompt} type="button" className="btn btn-primary portfolio">Portfolio</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary about">About</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary contact">Contact</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<TitleBar/>, document.getElementById('firstBar'));
```

Here's the `error` I'm getting:

```
    Uncaught SyntaxError: http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.js: Unexpected token (6:2)
    at Parser.pp.raise (browser.js:2027)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (browser.js:2596)
    at Parser.pp.expect (browser.js:2590)
    at Parser.pp.parseObj (browser.js:1447)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (browser.js:1250)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (browser.js:26392)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (browser.js:1097)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (browser.js:1079)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (browser.js:1035)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (browser.js:1018)
browser.js:9170 Uncaught SyntaxError: http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.js: Unexpected token (6:2)
    at Parser.pp.raise (browser.js:2027)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (browser.js:2596)
    at Parser.pp.expect (browser.js:2590)
    at Parser.pp.parseObj (browser.js:1447)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (browser.js:1250)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (browser.js:26392)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (browser.js:1097)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (browser.js:1079)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (browser.js:1035)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (browser.js:1018)
```

Comment: Missing , after property `prompt`.

Comment: missing comma between functions in the object

Comment: @www0z0k is it possible to include JQuery code in a render function()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `,` after `prompt` property,

```
var TitleBar = React.createClass({
  prompt: function() {
    alert("This works!");
  },

  render: function() {
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: Wow.... Silly me.  Thank you.  I sincerely apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: @Kyll maybe answer is not useful, however it is correct, also I can not delete it because chompy approved it. When chompy will remove accepted then I could delete my answer. Your downvote does not have reason, my answer is correct, you should downvore question not correct answer.

Comment: If you hover over the tooltip of downvotes, you can read _"This answer is not useful"_. I do fully agree that you are correct, however the solution to OP's issue was trivial and as such it is unlikely to help future visitors. You can also see that I close-voted the question. If you want to discuss this issue further, feel free to create a room in [chat] so as not to add noise to your answer (hence I am also deleting my previous comment).

Comment: @chompy could you unaccept my answer?